# Applying more CSS properties within one line

Tags: jquery, css

Is there any possible way to apply more than CSS to a control through a single line of code.In below example i could i apply only one property

```
$('#<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>').css("color", "#16428b");
```

Suppose if i would like to apply font or background.. how it is possible

-Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
.css({
    color: "#16428b",
    backgroundColor: "#f0f",
    "font-size" : "3em"
})
```

note the different styles of defining the CSS rules: camelCase for javascript, "css-style" for quoted strings.

This is also much more efficient than multiple chains of successive `.css()` calls, since it doesn't require multiple passes through your jQuery object.

Answer (score 4):

You just chain them:

```
$('#<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>')
   .css("color", "#16428b")
   .css("font-family", "Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif")
   .css("background", "#ccc");
```

Most methods in the jQuery object returns the jQuery object itself, so you just apply another method to the return value.

Edit:
If it's efficiency you are looking for it's of course best to update the element style directly:

```
var e = document.getElementById('<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>');
e.style.color = '#16428b';
e.style.fontFamily = 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif';
e.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
```

Answer (score 1):

Chain it.

```
$('#<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>').css("color", "#16428b").css("background","black");
```

Most Jquery functions return the Jquery object so you can do more stuff.

Alternatively, in the case of css, you can pass them in one properties object:

```
$('#<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>').css({color: "#16428b", background: "black"});
```

More info can be found here http://docs.jquery.com/CSS

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>').css("color", "#16428b").css("background", "1px solid red");
```

Will this do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery's css selector can take a [dictionary of options](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/css#properties).  So you could do this:

```
$('#<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>').css({ 
   "color": "#16428b", 
   fontWeight: "bold", 
   "float": "left", 
   "font-size": 2em 
});
```

Note that if you are not going to quote the property you need to camelCase it.  If you do quote it, using the hyphenated version is fine.